# Acces a specific character in a list

Tags: python

I have a list which I read through:

```
    doc= open('text.txt')
    d=doc.readlines()
```

But I need to go to the 10000th character and read the next 300 characters from there.To begin with, do you know how to read the list character-wise? thx!!

Comment: Do you mean the 10,000:th character on the line or the 10,000:th character in the file regardless of line breaks? In the former case, just read a single line with `line = doc.read()` and access `line[10000:10300]`

Comment: @tripleee yes, unless the file is very big, which makes a big read which could be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doc=open('text.txt').read()
```

opens the file as an entire string, which you can then slice from the 10000th character and get the next 300 chars, like so

```
doc[10000:10300]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
doc= open('text.txt')
d=doc.readlines()
```

that will provide you the list of lines. You need to use `read` instead.

I would

```
with open('text.txt') as doc:
   doc.read(10000)  # ignore result
   result = doc.read(300)  # read 300 chars from there.
```

Note that it could be faster if you used `doc.seek(100000)` instead of reading 10000 bytes "in the wind", but in that case, you have to account for CRLF conversion for MS-DOS text files, so you could have a different offset.